# Symfony 4 : How to have multi providers for user/admin in firewall?

Tags: symfony, symfony-security, symfony-4.2

I can not have two different providers for user and admin with two different forms

I want to have two firewalls, for users and for admins. I created two different providers linking two different entities. I can log in as a user, but never as Admin .. I do not understand what I need to add more.

Another thing, I know that there is app.user. But is there also app.admin? In order to have two completely separate accounts on two different firewalls?

```
security:
providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
    admin_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Admin
            property: username
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_provider, admin_provider]
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: user_provider
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
    backoffice:
        pattern: ^/backoffice
        provider: admin_provider
        logout:
            path: /backoffice/logout
            target: /backoffice/login
        form_login:
            login_path: /backoffice/login
            check_path: /backoffice/login
access_control:
    - { path: ^/backoffice/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/backoffice, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/mon-compte, roles: ROLE_USER }
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
    App\Entity\Admin:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
```

I have `null` error when I call `$authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch firewalls order, so the `main` firewall is the last one.

Symfony uses only one firewall per request and it's the first matched with the `pattern`. So in your case it's using `main` firewall for `^/backoffice` urls too because `/backoffice` matches `^/` pattern.

I'm not sure if it will solve all your issues here, but you need to do this in order to really use `backoffice` firewall.

Regarding `app.user` and `app.admin` - no, there's no `app.admin`. Admin is a user too, so when you'll be logged in as admin, you'll get its entity with `app.user`

Comment: Thank you, it helped me! I read your answer at the same time as I understood my mistake.

On my hand firewall, I have a user = test
And on my firewall admin I have a user = admin

Both can exist on two firewalls. It's a very good thing for me. Thank you anyway ! Resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated security.yaml :

```
security:
providers:
    admin_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Admin
            property: username
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_provider, admin_provider]
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    backoffice:
        pattern: ^/backoffice
        provider: admin_provider
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            path: admin.logout
            target: admin.login
        form_login:
            login_path: admin.login
            check_path: admin.login
            default_target_path: admin.index
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: user_provider
        anonymous: true
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: login
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
access_control:
    - { path: ^/backoffice/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/backoffice, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/mon-compte, roles: ROLE_USER }
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
    App\Entity\Admin:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
```